# Selenium IDE: altKeyDown() + "click" not Saving Target As

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to have Firefox "Save Target As" by using Alt+Click.  This works in Firefox when I do it myself (I've update Firefox settings to enable Alt+click to save target as). When I try it in Selenium IDE it does not replicate the same functionality when preceding the Click event with altKeyDown().

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=ctl00</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>altKeyDown</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Document</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Selenium IDE is powered, backed and limited by JavaScript.

Therefore, every action you do in Selenium IDE (and Selenium RC which is the old Selenium engine, so to say) is "just" JavaScript and has the same abilities as such. Obviously, you can't force "Save Target As" by running any JS on a page, that would be a possible security hole, because any page on the internet could enforce your browser to download any files.

Also, you can't really emulate pressing the buttons with JS to make it OS-level event to make Firefox "hear" it. When done by JS, it's "just" a document-level event mostly for other JS scripts on the page to know about it.

This limitation (among many others) has led the Selenium developers to abandon Selenium RC in favor of Selenium WebDriver (also known as Selenium 2) which uses native interactions with the browser, if it can. [But even that can't yet download files](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=95) in a reliable way.

That said, pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and clicking in WebDriver is simple thanks to the Advanced User Interactions API [and will work on most browser and OS combinations out there](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#advanceduserinteractions) (Java example):

```java
new Actions(driver)
    .keyDown(Keys.ALT)
    .click(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00")))
    .keyUp(Keys.ALT)
    .perform();
```

If your combination is not supported yet, this action will only emit emulated key press, which, again, Firefox can't hear. In that case, you'll need your language's tools to cope with that (for example, the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int%29) class in Java).

Also, you can export your existing test scripts from IDE to WebDriver-like Java or C# code easily.